# yum does not contain the package: libcurl

Tags: yum, rhel5, curl

I am in Redhat 5 and the following packages are not found

```
yum -y install libcurl libcurl-devel
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
No package libcurl available.
No package libcurl-devel available.
Nothing to do
```

Weird! What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7):

Unless you're looking for some specific version a 3rd party package has been compiled against, it's called curl-devel in RHEL 5.

`yum install curl-devel`

```
# rpm -qpl curl-devel-7.15.5-17.el5_9.x86_64.rpm | grep libcurl
/usr/lib64/libcurl.a
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc
/usr/share/man/man3/libcurl-easy.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libcurl-errors.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libcurl-multi.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libcurl-share.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libcurl-tutorial.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libcurl.3.gz
```

This is straight out of the distribution's repository, no 3rd party repository necessary.

Comment: You can also use
`yum search curl`
to help locate packages that are available in your current repository set.